# Need help in designing responsive column using data tables (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable-buttons"
    class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap sub-user-table mb-0"
    style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
    <thead class="xsite_thead_background">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Permissions</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in sub_admins %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.user.first_name }} </td>
                <td>{{ row.user.email }} </td>
                <td><a href="#" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover">View</a></td>


                <td>
                    <div aria-label="Basic example">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i
                                class="mdi mdi-grease-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button myid={{ row.id }} type="button"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-admin" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#deleteusermodal">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-trash-can-outline"></i>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
             {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to build a responsive table with 'DataTable - JS'. everything seems good, except when the column data exceed in length.
This is a table
[image]

and this is when td length exceed
[image]

I want to git rid of this scroll, instead of x-scroll text should display in the new row. I have also tried overflow-x: hidden; but it crops the text.

Comment: Can you show us your DataTables definition so we can recreate the problem you are facing? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @andrewjames I am using a jQuery plugin - Datatables

Comment: OK - but can you show us your DataTables definition so we can recreate the problem you are facing? Show us your code.

Comment: I have added the code above. please let me know if you need anything else.
@andrewjames

Comment: Remove the `nowrap` class from the `<table>` tag.